# Running a prerelease test fails with Python ImportError

Tags: ros, python, ros-kinetic, python3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey everyone,

I am currently trying on publishing a ROS package and following the [Realeasing A Package](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/ReleasingAPackage) guide. So far I've added my package name to the rosdistro for kinetic and verified its readiness before. Unfortunately, I can't manage to [execute a prerelease test](http://wiki.ros.org/regression_tests#How_do_I_setup_my_system_to_run_a_prerelease.3F). I get stuck at the 4th step of section 5.2. When I run  the generated command (which is shown below), I get the following error:

The command:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/prerelease_job
cd /tmp/prerelease_job
generate_prerelease_script.py \
  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros-infrastructure/ros_buildfarm_config/production/index.yaml \
  kinetic default ubuntu xenial amd64 \
  robot_statemachine \
  --level 1 \
  --output-dir ./
```

The error output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/generate_prerelease_script.py", line 35, in <module>
    from ros_buildfarm.config import get_index as get_config_index
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ros_buildfarm/config/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    import yaml
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from error import *
ImportError: No module named 'error'
```

So far, I've tried with the first suggestion under 5.1, installing the `python3-ros-buildfarm` which produced the above error. Then I removed it, and installed `python-ros-buildfarm`, also installing the dependencies required in the second purple box under section 5.1. With this the prerelease script could be built but it produced the following error when I ran it:

prerelease.sh output with python-ros-buildfarm:

```
Prerelease script

By default this script will continue even if tests fail.
If you want the script to abort and return a non-zero return code
you can set the environment variable ABORT_ON_TEST_FAILURE=1.
You can also set ABORT_ON_TEST_FAILURE_UNDERLAY=1 or
ABORT_ON_TEST_FAILURE_OVERLAY=1 to only affect a specific workspace.

Use workspace: /tmp/prerelease_job


Clone source repositories for underlay workspace

+ git clone --recurse-submodules -b master https://github.com/MarcoStb1993/robot_statemachine.git ws/src/robot_statemachine
Cloning into 'ws/src/robot_statemachine'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 63, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (63/63), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (41/41), done.
remote: Total 936 (delta 31), reused 37 (delta 19), pack-reused 873
Receiving objects: 100% (936/936), 1.90 MiB | 587.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (627/627), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
+ git -C ws/src/robot_statemachine --no-pager log -n 1
commit 6217fdb14c265dbf85b4688b730f8514caf30efa
Author: MarcoStb1993 <35468630+MarcoStb1993@users.noreply.github.com>
Date:   Thu Aug 1 12:05:33 2019 +0200

    Delete .project



Clone release repositories for overlay workspace

Underlay workspace contains 6 packages:
- robot_statemachine
- statemachine
- statemachine_additions
- statemachine_msgs
- statemachine_rqt_plugins
- statemachine_rviz_plugins
Overlay packages based on dependency level: 0
Overlay packages based on whitelisted package names: 0
Overlay workspace will contain 0 packages:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/vcs", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('vcstool==0.2.2', 'console_scripts', 'vcs')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 542, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2569, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2229, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2235, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/vcstool/commands/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .import_ import ImportCommand
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/vcstool/commands/import_.py", line 13, in <module>
    import yaml
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from error import *
ImportError: No module named 'error'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 15, in <module>
    from configparser import ConfigParser, NoOptionError, NoSectionError
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/configparser.py", line 397
    _KEYCRE = re.compile(ur"%\(([^)]+)\)s")
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/vcs", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('vcstool==0.2.2', 'console_scripts', 'vcs')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 542, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2569, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2229, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2235, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/vcstool/commands/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .import_ import ImportCommand
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/vcstool/commands/import_.py", line 13, in <module>
    import yaml
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from error import *
ImportError: No module named 'error'
```

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 with ROS Kinetic on a VMWare Workstation with a Windows Host. Here is the link to the package I am trying to test: [Robot Statemachine](https://github.com/MarcoStb1993/robot_statemachine).

This is the result of `echo $PYTHONPATH`:

```
/home/marco/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

Edit: And the Python versions:

```
which python: /usr/bin/python
which python3: /usr/bin/python3
python --version: Python 2.7.12
python3 --version: Python 3.5.2
```

Any help resolving this issue would be appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329848/running-a-prerelease-test-fails-with-python-importerror/) by [MarcoStb](https://answers.ros.org/users/34552/marcostb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 80 on 2019-08-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-08-02**:
off-topic, but: is your package really called `statemachine`? That is a really generic name and I'm surprised your [ros/rosdistro#21873](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/21873) was merged.

I can only make the suggestion that you rename your packages to something more descriptive and unique. Refer to [REP 144: ROS Package Naming](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0144.html) for some rationale on why using descriptive names is much preferred over using generic ones.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-08-02**:
As to the error message: you appear to be mixing Python 2.7 and Python 3 modules and interpreters.

What is the output of `which python`, `which python3` and `python --version`?

**Comment by [MarcoStb](https://answers.ros.org/users/34552/marcostb/) on 2019-08-02**:
Hm, yes, now that you say it ...
It is bundled in a metapackage called `robot_statemachine` though, if that makes it any better.

**Comment by [MarcoStb](https://answers.ros.org/users/34552/marcostb/) on 2019-08-02**:
I supsected this to be the case, but I was not able to fix it on my own.
Here are the outputs:

- `which python`: `/usr/bin/python`
- `which python3`: `/usr/bin/python3`
- `python --version`: `Python 2.7.12`
- `python3 --version`: `Python 3.5.2`

Added them to the post as well.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-08-02**:\

> Hm, yes, now that you say it ...
> It is bundled in a metapackage called `robot_statemachine` though, if that makes it any better.

Not really.

Metapackages don't "bundle" other packages. They merely provide convenience.

I've written something about them in #q256493.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Here are the outputs:

> - `which python`: `/usr/bin/python`
> - `python --version`: `Python 2.7.12`

The default Python interpreter appears to be Python 2.7 on your system. The Python scripts in the `ros_buildfarm` package only specify `python` as the required interpreter ([here](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/ros_buildfarm/blob/f1eaeb85e5536e03c0764895d6ed782701906d1f/scripts/prerelease/generate_prerelease_script.py#L1) fi), so on your system that will result in Python2 being used. This can lead to the problems that you experienced.

I believe you should either execute the script as `python3 generate_prerelease_script.py ..` or create a `virtualenv` with only Python 3 enabled and use that to run the scripts and tests.

Personally I would recommend the `virtualenv` approach.

I can't access the wiki page you link to right now (host appears to be busy with other things), but at least the `ros_buildfarm` [Setup environment to deploy configuration](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/ros_buildfarm/blob/f1eaeb85e5536e03c0764895d6ed782701906d1f/doc/environment.rst) document suggests using a `virtualenv` as well.

---

Edit: the following steps work for me to create a `virtualenv` with all dependencies installed:

```
virtualenv -p python3 $HOME/venv_ros_buildfarm
source $HOME/venv_ros_buildfarm/bin/activate
pip3 install empy
pip3 install jenkinsapi
pip3 install rosdistro
pip3 install ros_buildfarm
```

At this point all the scripts in `ros_buildfarm` should be available and all use the `python3` interpreter.

You'll have to activate this `virtualenv` whenever you want to run the prerelease test(s) as well I believe.

---

Edit 2: `venv` setup steps were updated in [ros-infrastructure/ros_buildfarm#658](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/ros_buildfarm/pull/658).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MarcoStb](https://answers.ros.org/users/34552/marcostb/) on 2019-08-02**:
Thanks for the response, but unfortunately I couldn't manage to get virtualenv running. I followed the approach in [Setup environment to deploy configuration](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/ros_buildfarm/blob/f1eaeb85e5536e03c0764895d6ed782701906d1f/doc/environment.rst#virtualenv) but at the command `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3` I got the following error:

```
File "/tmp/tmphgxcgthz/pip.zip/pip/_internal/wheel.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/compileall.py", line 20, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/concurrent/futures/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures._base import (FIRST_COMPLETED,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 357
    raise type(self._exception), self._exception, self._traceback
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**Comment by [MarcoStb](https://answers.ros.org/users/34552/marcostb/) on 2019-08-02**:
I don't know how to run the first approach. When I try it, I get the following output:
`python3: can't open file 'generate_prerelease_script.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-08-02**:
`pip` is typically already installed in a `virtualenv`. I would drop the `--without-pip` when creating the `virtualenv`.

And you obviously also don't need to use Python 3.4, just use whatever Python version you have.

Btw: it would seem even this command mixes Python 2 and 3 modules. Are you automatically `source`ing (multiple) workspaces in your `.bashrc` or something similar?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-08-02**:\

> I don't know how to run the first approach. When I try it, I get the following output:
> `python3: can't open file 'generate_prerelease_script.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`.

that's because you probably don't have the Python 3 version installed any more:

> Then I removed it

In any case: I would use a `virtualenv`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-08-02**:
I've added the steps that work for me, but I have the impression that your Python setup may be in a bit of a weird state, seeing the error messages you show mix Python 2.7 and Python 3 paths.

**Comment by [MarcoStb](https://answers.ros.org/users/34552/marcostb/) on 2019-08-02**:
Thanks a lot for your help! Without the `--without-pip` and using only `pyvenv venv` it seems to be working (still building stuff, but that's probably a good sign).
I know my Python setup seems to be really messed up, I'll try to clean it up soon.
Also, you were right about the `.bashrc`, I was sourcing the ros and my local catkin workspace in there. I've commented those out.
Do you know if it is possible to setup the `virtualenv` so that I don't have to install `empy, jenkinsapi, rosdistro` and `ros_buildfarm` every time anew?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-08-02**:\

> Do you know if it is possible to setup the `virtualenv` so that I don't have to install `empy, jenkinsapi, rosdistro` and `ros_buildfarm` every time anew?

that's not something that I recognise and should not be necessary. Unless you create the `virtualenv` in your `/tmp` of course.

Are you confused by this statement:

> You'll have to activate this `virtualenv` whenever you want to run the prerelease test(s) as well I believe.

`activate != recreate`. The `virtualenv` will persist. You just need to `source /path/to/your/virtualenv/bin/activate` every time you want to use it.

**Comment by [MarcoStb](https://answers.ros.org/users/34552/marcostb/) on 2019-08-03**:
Thanks again for clarifying and helping me out so much! I never used `virtualenv` before, so wasn't quite sure what I was doing.  o
I found out that the scripts are not working as soon as I have sourced `/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` or `/home/user/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`. If I open a new terminal, the commands will be executed without an issue, even without a `virtualenv`. I guess this probably isn't normal behaviours ...

**Comment by [achille](https://answers.ros.org/users/30659/achille/) on 2020-01-02**:
That might have been because your PYTHONPATH contained python2 paths.